# Is it possible to code for tradingview not using Pine Script?

Tags: javascript, python, pine-script

I am trying to code in Pine Script but as you may know it doesn't make sense at all, I can't figure it up how it lifecycle works.

Is there an alternative way to code for it? C sharp, JavaScript, Python and .... anything?

Comment: We can only dream as for TV's decision to YASL is beyond me in my wildest dreams.  These half baked scripting language creations should be avoided.  I didn't think you could make a scripting language worse than JavaScript, alas PineScript was born.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

The way that Pine Script works is very different from classical programming languages.
To gain an understanding of how it works, you should first read about the [Execution model](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Execution_model.html) of Pine.

Another excellent resource is [PineCoders](https://www.pinecoders.com/).